# IEEE conference template opens with strange characters in Mac

Tags: overleaf, texshop, font-encodings

I am trying to open a template in LaTex for IEEE conferences with TexShop and I am getting a message that says.

"This file was opened with ISOLatin9 encoding. The file could not be opened with Unicode (UTF-8) encoding because it was not saved with that encoding. If you wish to open in another encoding, close the window and open again."

What happens is that I get some strange characters that does not appear in the template compiled pdf and I cannot really compile it myself (Invalide utf-8 byte sequence). In Overleaf it allows me to compile it, but both the original and compiled versions have weird characters (for some of them, overleaf ignores them and gives and error message:

"LaTeX Error: Command \DH unavailable in encoding OT1."

This is probably a very silly issue related with encodings, but I am losing a lot of time and I am not really getting it. I am a MAC user, I think this is relevant for the issue but still do not know how to solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a few weird characters in the provided template `root.tex` file that causes the error. You will want to find and delete all the instances of these two characters: `Ò` `Ó`. Also, find and replace all instances of `Ð` with `-` to resolve this error.